# android slidingMenu show nothing

Tags: android, xml

MainActivity:

```
    slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    slidingMenu.setBehindOffset(R.dimen.sliding_menu_offset);
    slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this,SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu);
```

sliding_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff8990">

    <com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/slidingmenu">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Check me!"
            android:background="#0f0"/>
    </com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu>
</LinearLayout>
```

when i show the slidingMenu,there is nothing?just a white background
[image: this the picture]

Comment: Instead of `slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);` use `slidingMenu = (SlidingMenu) findViewById(R.id.slidingmenu)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);`to `SlidingMenu menu = getSlidingMenu();`

try adopting the following code...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

setBehindContentView(R.layout.testing);

populate();

SlidingMenu menu = getSlidingMenu();

slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
slidingMenu.setBehindOffset(R.dimen.sliding_menu_offset);
slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this,SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu);

}
```

Comment: "getSlidingMenu() cannot be solved". How can I use getSlidingMenu()?

Comment: Cannot be resolved to a type suggests that you haven't added SlidingMenu to the libraries  in the project props. fix your imports and try again. 
You need to have  android-support-v4 JAR in both of you libs directory of  slidingmenulibrary and  libs folder of your project.

Go to  SDK folder and go to sdk\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar.Copy this jar and paste it into both directories.
.

Comment: I add android-support-v4.jar to \app\libs and \libraries\library\libs, Sync project with Gradle files, then rebuild my project, but getSlidingMenu() cannot be solved.(i use AndroidStudio)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that library specifically but it looks like you put your sliding menu inside the menu...

Isn't the view com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu supposed to be in the activity view hierarchy?

If so, the *com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu* declaration in the xml is used to declare and position in the activity the sliding menu view. The sliding menu itself should probably be a regular view that the library can inflate.

Answer (score 0):

I gat it!
Before I manually add SlidingMenu/library to AS, and then change the contents of the library of  bulid.gradle and setting.gradle, that there may be some places there is an error that has caused can not be displayed.
Now, I let AS automatically add 'library', it can be executed